# How to make #description appear on a field widget?

Tags: forms

I have a custom field widget that extends WidgetBase. My formElement method looks like this:

```
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element['value'] = $element + [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $items[$delta]->value ?? NULL,
      '#size' => $this->getSetting('size'),
      '#placeholder' => $this->getSetting('placeholder'),
      '#maxlength' => $this->getFieldSetting('max_length'),
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['js-text-full', 'text-full']],
      '#description' => $this->t('test description'),
      '#description_display' => 'after',
    ];

    return $element;
  }
```

The description does not display.
Adding the xdebug output for the widget when the node form loads:

```
Array
(
    [#title] => field test
    [#title_display] => before
    [#description] => 
    [#field_parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#required] => 
    [#delta] => 0
    [#weight] => 0
    [#type] => textfield
    [#default_value] => 
    [#size] => 60
    [#placeholder] => 
    [#maxlength] => 255
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => js-text-full
                    [1] => text-full
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: When I put #deccription in a field widget it does appear. There has to be more than what you are telling right now. Did you try a different theme? I'm using Claro.

Comment: I’ll try that. I note that none of the examples of creating a custom field contain #description with the field, nor did any of the several field type modules, while it is used in an example as one of the things you can with the custom field module. So I was beginning to think it’s simply not passed along somewhere.

Comment: It's part of the official FORM API, but they advise against it. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/form-render-elements - This might explain why it's not used as often.

Comment: I'm using Claro, as well. Just to verify, your use of "field widget" is the Plugins/Field/FieldWidget type, not a custom form, right? I see that you mentioned the form API, but this is the field API. In terms of my use of it, the rationale is almost exactly the same as the file upload field having help text that specifies the valid file types.

Comment: Hey @JAyenGreen, As a quick test, try replacing `$this->t('test description')` with a hardcoded string like 'Test Description' and see if the description appears. This helps to isolate whether the translation function is the issue. if so, you need to wrapped it back with `t()`, and check Language Configuration.

Comment: Using static text didn't fix it, but nice suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, oddly enough, it turns out there was either a flaw in the example I had borrowed or there was some subtle difference in the context.

I became suspicious of the very first line of the function:

```
$element['value'] = $element + [
```

and, indeed, when I changed it to:

```
$element['value'] = [
```

the description text appeared. Very odd.

Comment: Good find +1. The explanation for the odd behavior is that the field loads the description from the field configuration and stores it at the top level of $element. The `+` on arrays ignores duplicate keys on the right side. When using the usual `+` in field widgets for the other metadata you could override the description in an extra code line `$element['value']['#description'] = 'foo';`